# jquery change attribute of icheck plugin

Tags: jquery, icheck

I have this code to style a checkbox using the iCheck plugin for jquery, is there a way to change the 'insert' attribute later?. I tried recreating the iCheck but the callback function is deleted if I do it that way.

```js
$(this).iCheck({
    checkboxClass: checkboxClass,
    insert: '<div class="icheck_line-icon"></div>' + $(this).attr("data-label")
});

$(this).on({ifChecked: function(){
    iCheckChange(this, yes);
},ifUnchecked: function(){
    iCheckChange(this, no);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have checkboxes in this format:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="my_checkbox" data-label="Check me" />
```

Than you can change your icon and text this way:

```
var checkboxClass = 'checkbox_cls';
$('.my_checkbox').each(function(i) {
    var thisCheckbox=$(this);
    thisCheckbox.iCheck({
        checkboxClass: checkboxClass,
        insert: '<div class="icheck_line-icon"></div><span class="insert_label">' + thisCheckbox.data("label") + '</span>'
    });
    var thisIcon = thisCheckbox.siblings('.icheck_line-icon');
    var thisLabel = thisCheckbox.siblings('.insert_label');
    thisCheckbox.on('ifChecked', function(e){
        thisIcon.addClass('icon-checked');
        thisLabel.html('Im checked');
    });
    thisCheckbox.on('ifUnchecked', function(e){
        thisIcon.removeClass('icon-checked');
        thisLabel.html('Not checked');
    });
});
```

Take a look at **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju1zprhk/)**.