# How to change check icon by cross icon using iCheck js plugin on checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I'm using iCheck js plugin to show my checkboxes. I want to change the icon showed when I check it. Instead of a red check icon, I want to show red cross icon.

My code is this:

**JS**

```
$('.inputiCheck').iCheck({
   checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-red',
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="inputiCheck">
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Refer this - http://www.csscheckbox.com/

Comment: Something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610485/jquery-change-attribute-of-icheck-plugin  ?

Comment: Your question has been answered in this other thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610485/jquery-change-attribute-of-icheck-plugin.